# Motion action up when moving from view to view without lifting finger from the screen

Tags: java, android, motion

This is my third question on the same topic. I am making a **phone dialer app** for **blind people** for a client and I want to move from button to button without finger lifting the screen and playing sound of the number when finger stop on button and if he want that button to get typed he left his finger and so on I found this code in previous question and it work only if finger is moving but if I lift my finger I can't get anything to happen, so my question how to get to get action when I lift my finger from the button and **how deal with every button individually?**

```
package com.example.touch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyButton b1, b2, b3, b4;

    int b1x1, b1x2, b1y1, b1y2;

    private TextView xcordview;
    private TextView ycordview;
    private TextView buttonIndicator;
    private RelativeLayout touchview;
    private static int defaultStates[];
    private Button mLastButton;
    private final static int[] STATE_PRESSED = {
            android.R.attr.state_pressed,
            android.R.attr.state_focused  
                    | android.R.attr.state_enabled };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        xcordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ycordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        buttonIndicator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_indicator);
        touchview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);

        b1 = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        defaultStates = b1.getBackground().getState();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        touchview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private boolean isInside = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(y));

                for (int i = 0; i < touchview.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View current = touchview.getChildAt(i);
                    if (current instanceof Button) {
                        Button b = (Button) current;

                        if (!isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(defaultStates);
                            b.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                        }

                        if (isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(STATE_PRESSED);
                            b.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                            b.performClick();

                            if (b != mLastButton) {
                                mLastButton = b;
                                buttonIndicator.setText(mLastButton.getText());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    static boolean isPointWithin(int x, int y, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        return (x <= x2 && x >= x1 && y <= y2 && y >= y1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should write above code in if condition of ACTION_MOVE/ ACTION_DOWN and add another if condition of ACTION_UP  for action finger left (up) from display. you can follow for reference  [1]: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.MotionEvent

Comment: it worked thanks a lot but action move get executed rabidly so i want it to get executed only once and how can i use every button individually

Comment: if you want it to execute only then you can use a **boolean variable** for it and do something like `if(getAction == ACTION_MOVE && !urBooleanVariable )` . initially set that boolean variable to `false` and then set it to `true` on `ACTION_MOVE`  and again set it to`false` on `ACTION_UP` . And yes you can use it for each button individually  by setting touch listener to each button . it will simplify your logic also . :)